# command link not working after rerender

Tags: visualforce

My requirement is to show a dropdown with year values as 2012,2013,2014,2015. If user selects year as 2014 I need to rerender output panel which shows records with year as 2014. likewise for other years.

If user clicks on any record, page should pass the record id to other vf page. For this am using command Link and apex param to redirect.
On page load am displaying all records irrespective of years. In this case command link is working but if I select any specific year, rerender is happening but command link is not working.

```
   <apex:selectList value="{!programYearValue}" style="font-size:12px" id="pyid" multiselect="false" size="1" styleClass="form-control">

     <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!pastProgList}" reRender="pastEvts,cmdLink" /> 
           <apex:selectOptions value="{!programYears}"/>

   /apex:selectList>


apex:outputPanel id="pastEvts">

                   <apex:repeat var="pastEvents" value="{!pastEventsList}">
                    <apex:commandLink action="{!redirecttoEventPast}" id="cmdLink" style="color:black"> 

                    <div class="col-lg-4">

                        <div class="widget panel">
                            <!-- panel body -->
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <ul class="list-table">
                                    <li style="width:70px;">
                                        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!programType  == 'Young Runner'}">
                                            <img class="img-circle img-bordered" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Resources, 'Resources/image/avatar/yrAvatarLogo.png')}" alt="" width="65px"/>
                                       </apex:outputPanel> 


                                    </li>
                                    <li class="text-left">
                                        <h5 class="semibold">
                                            {!pastEvents.Name}<br/>
                                            <small class="text-muted">{!pastEvents.Location__c}</small>
                                        </h5>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>
                                <!-- Nav section -->
                                <ul class="nav nav-section nav-justified mt15">
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="section">
                                            <h5 class="semibold"><apex:outputText value=" {!pastEvents.Event_Date__c}"/></h5><br/>
                                            <small class="nm text-muted">{!pastEvents.Event_Day__c}</small>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>

                                    <li>
                                        <div class="section">
                                           <h5 class="semibold">{!pastEvents.Kids_Who_Attended_Event__c}</h5><br/>
                                           <small class="nm text-muted">Kids Attended</small>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <!--/ Nav section -->
                            </div>
                            <!--/ panel body -->
                        </div>

                    </div>
                        <apex:param name="programId" value="{!pastEvents.Id}" assignTo="{!eventId}"/> 

                       </apex:commandLink> 
                 </apex:repeat>

                 </apex:outputPanel>
```

Please help me out if am missing any logic here. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide the whole VF page?

Comment: Please post the associated controllers as well.